# Fastest way to copy files (but not the entire directory) from one location to another

Tags: powershell, data-migration, robocopy

**Summary**

- I am currently tasked with migrating around 6TB of data to a cloud server, and am trying to optimise how fast this can be done.
- I would use standard Robocopy to do this usually, but there is a requirement that I am to only transfer files that are present in a filetable in SQL, and not the entire directories (due to a lot of junk being inside these folders that we do not want to migrate).

**What I have tried**

Feeding in individual files from an array into Robocopy is unfeasibly slow, as Robocopy instances were being started sequentially for each file, so I tried to speed up this process in 2 ways.

1. It was pointless to have /MT set above 1 if only one file was being transferred, so I attempted to simulate the multithreading feature. I did this by utilising the new [ForEach-Object –Parallel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/) feature in PowerShell 7.0, and setting the throttle limit to 4. With this, I was able to pass the array in and run 4 Robocopy jobs in parallel (still starting and stopping for each file), which increased speed a bit.
2. Secondly, I split the array into 4 equal arrays, and ran the above function across each array as a job, which again increased the speed by quite a bit. For clarity, I had equal 4 arrays fed to 4 ForEach-Object -Parallel code blocks that were running 4 Robocopy instances, so a total of 16 Robocopy instances at once.

**Issues**

I encountered a few problems.

1. My simulation of the **multithreading feature did not behave** in the way that the /MT flag works in Robocopy. When examining the processes running, my code executes 16 instances of Robocopy at once, whereas the normal /MT:16 flag of Robocopy would only kick off one Robocopy instance (but still be multithreading).
2. Secondly, the code causes a **memory leak**. The memory usage starts to increase when the jobs and accumulates over time, until a large portion of memory is being utilised. When the jobs complete, the memory usage is still high until I close PowerShell and the memory is released. Normal Robocopy did not do this.
3. Finally, I decided to compare the time taken for my method, and then a standard Robocopy of the entire testing directory, and the normal Robocopy was still over **10x faster**, and had a better success rate (a lot of the files weren’t copied over with my code, and a lot of the time I was receiving error messages that the files were currently in use and couldn’t be Robocopied, presumably because they were in the process of being Robocopied).

Are there any faster alternatives, or is there a way to manually create a multithreading instance of robocopy that would perform like the /MT flag of the standard robocopy? I appreciate any insight/alternative ways of looking at this. Thanks!

```
#Item(0) is the Source excluding the filename, Item(2) is the Destination, Item(1) is the filename
$robocopy0 = $tables.Tables[0].Rows
$robocopy1 = $tables.Tables[1].Rows
$robocopy0 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {robocopy $_.Item(0) $_.Item(2) $_.Item(1) /e /w:1 /r:1 /tee /NP /xo /mt:1 /njh /njs /ns 
                                      } -ThrottleLimit 4 -AsJob
$robocopy1 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {robocopy $_.Item(0) $_.Item(2) $_.Item(1) /e /w:1 /r:1 /tee /NP /xo /mt:1 /njh /njs /ns 
                                      } -ThrottleLimit 4 -AsJob
#*8 for 8 arrays
```

Answer (score 0):

RunspaceFactory multithreading might be optimally suited for this type of work--with one HUGE caveat.  There are quite a few articles out on the net about it.  Essentially you create a scriptblock that takes parameters for the source file to copy and the destination to write to and uses those parameters to execute robocopy against it.  You create individual PowerShell instances to execute each variant of the scriptblock and append it to the RunspaceFactory.  The RunspaceFactory will queue up the jobs and work against the probably millions of jobs X number at a time, where X is equal to the number of threads you allocate for the factory.

CAVEAT:  First and foremost, to queue up millions of jobs relative to the probable millions of files you have across 6TB, you'll likely need monumental amounts of memory.  Assuming an average path length for source and destination of 40 characters (probably very generous) * a WAG of 50 million files is nearly 4GB in memory by itself, which doesn't include object structural overhead, the PowerShell instances, etc.  You can overcome this either breaking up the job into smaller chunks or use a server with 128GB RAM or better.  Additionally, if you don't terminate the jobs once they've been processed, you'll also experience what appears to be a memory leak but is just your jobs producing information that you're not closing when completed.

Here's a sample from a recent project I did migrating files from an old domain NAS to a new domain NAS -- I'm using Quest SecureCopy instead of RoboCopy but you should be able to easily replace those bits:

```
## MaxThreads is an arbitrary number I use relative to the hardware I have available to run jobs I'm working on.
$FileRSpace_MaxThreads = 15
$FileRSpace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $FileRSpace_MaxThreads, ([System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState]::CreateDefault()), $Host)
$FileRSpace.ApartmentState = 'MTA'
$FileRSpace.Open()

## The scriptblock that does the actual work.
$sb = {
param(
    $sp,
    $dp
)

    ## This is my output object I'll emit through STDOUT so I can consume the status of the job in the main thread after each instance is completed.
    $n = [pscustomobject]@{
        'source'  = $sp
        'dest'    = $dp
        'status'  = $null
        'sdtm'    = [datetime]::Now
        'edtm'    = $null
        'elapsed' = $null
    }

    ## Remove the Import-Module and SecureCopy cmdlet and replace it with the RoboCopy version
    try {
        Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Quest\Secure Copy 7\SCYPowerShellCore.dll" -ErrorAction Stop
        Start-SecureCopyJob -Database "C:\Program Files\Quest\Secure Copy 7\SecureCopy.ssd" -JobName "Default" -Source $sp -Target $dp -CopySubFolders $true -Quiet $true -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
        $n.status = $true
    } catch {
        $n.status = $_
    }
    $n.edtm    = [datetime]::Now
    $n.elapsed = ("{0:N2} minutes" -f (($n.edtm - $n.sdtm).TotalMinutes))
    $n        
}

## The array to hold the individual runspaces and ulitimately iterate over to watch for completion.
$FileWorkers = @()

$js = [datetime]::now
log "Job starting at $js"

## $peers is a [pscustomobject] I precreate that just contains every source (property 's') and the destination (property 'd') -- modify to suit your needs as necessary
foreach ($c in $peers) {

    try {

        log "Configuring migration job for '$($c.s)' and '$($c.d)'"
        $runspace = [powershell]::Create()
        [void]$runspace.AddScript($sb)

        [void]$runspace.AddArgument($c.s)
        [void]$runspace.AddArgument($c.d)

        $runspace.RunspacePool = $FileRSpace
        $FileWorkers += [pscustomobject]@{
            'Pipe'   = $runspace
            'Async'  = $runspace.BeginInvoke()
        }

        log "Successfully created a multi-threading job for '$($c.s)' and '$($c.d)'"
    } catch {
        log "An error occurred creating a multi-threading job for '$($c.s)' and '$($c.d)'"
    }
}

while ($FileWorkers.Async.IsCompleted -contains $false) {
    $Completed = $FileWorkers | ? { $_.Async.IsCompleted -eq $true }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        'Numbers' = ("{0}/{1}" -f $Completed.Count, $FileWorkers.Count)
        'PercComplete' = ("{0:P2}" -f ($Completed.Count / $FileWorkers.Count))
        'ElapsedMins' = ("{0:N2}" -f ([datetime]::Now - $js).TotalMinutes)
    }

    $Completed | % { $_.Pipe.EndInvoke($_.Async) } | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation ".\$($DtmStamp)_SecureCopy_Results.csv"

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
}

## This is to handle a race-condition where the final job(s) aren't completed before the sleep but do when the while is re-eval'd
$FileWorkers | % { $_.Pipe.EndInvoke($_.Async) } | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation ".\$($DtmStamp)_SecureCopy_Results.csv"
```

Suggested strategies if you don't have a beefy server to queue up all the jobs simultaneously is to either batch out the files in statically sized blocks (e.g. 100,000 or whatever your hw can take) or you could group files together to send to each script block (e.g. 100 files per scriptblock) which would minimize the number of jobs to queue up in the runspace factory (but would require some code change).

HTH

Edit 1:  To Address constructing the input object I'm using

```
$destRoot = '\\destinationserver.com\share'

$peers = @()

$children = @()
$children += (get-childitem '\\sourceserver\share' -Force) | Select -ExpandProperty FullName 

foreach ($c in $children) {

    $peers += [pscustomobject]@{
        's' = $c
        'd' = "$($destRoot)\$($c.Split('\')[3])\$($c | Split-Path -Leaf)"
    }
}
```

In my case, I was taking stuff from \server1\share1\subfolder1 and moving it to something like \server2\share1\subfolder1\subfolder2.  So in essence, all the '$peers' array is doing is constructing an object that took in the fullname of the source target and constructing the corresponding destination path (since the source/dest server names are different and possibly share name too).

You don't have to do this, you can dynamically construct the destination and just loop through the source folders.  I perform this extra step because now I have a two property array that I can verify is pre-constructed accurately as well as perform tests to ensure things exist and are accessible.

There is a lot of extra bloat in my script due to custom objects meant to give me output from each thread put into the multi-threader so I can see the status of each copy attempt--to track things like folders that were successful or not, how long it took to perform that individual copy, etc.  If you're using robocopy and dumping the results to a text file, you may not need this.  If you want me to pair down script to it's barebone components just to get things multi-threading, I can do that if you like.

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for the response! Apologies, I'm relatively new to this role and couldn't really get my head round your script. Also, I think I may have been ambiguous. There is around 6TB but we will be handling this on a folder by folder basis as we migrate project data over. Also, I have split the files into separate Jobs depending on the filename. Would your solution still work? I was confused about how i could feed separate arrays into the $sp/$dp (source path/destiantion path?)

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. Fortunately, I've discovered the /if flag for robocopy (opposite of /xf) where I can specify which files to include. Took a good while to get robocopy to read the files (had to create the files as an array in powershell), but this sees speeds just as fast as normal robocopy!

Comment: No worries -- glad you found a solution.  That's what it's all about.